# Delete the word whose length is less than 2 in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I am using bash on CentOS 5.5. I have a string separated by space , and the string only contain alphabets and numbers, and this string may have extra space, for example, there are more than 1 space between `"words"` and `"string"`:

```
$exmple= "This is a lovey 7 words   string"
```

I want to delete the word whose length is less than 2, in this example, the word `"a"` and `"7"` need to be deleted. And delete all the extra space, only one space between one word and another.

so the string becomes:

```
"This is lovey words string"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** (based on ennuikiller's `sed` answer)

Using pure Bash:

```
newstring=${exmple// ? / }   # remove one character words
```

To normalize the whitespace:

```
read newstring <<< $newstring
```

or

```
shopt -s extglob
newstring=${newstring//+( )/ }
```

**Original:**

```
exmple="This is a lovey 7 words   string"
for word in $exmple
do
    if (( ${#word} >= 2 ))
    then
        newstring+=$sp$word
        sp=' '
    fi
done
```

Comment: An error: `/usr/local/sbin/testbash: line 1: This is a lovey 7 words   string: command not found`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Could you please take a look at your command? The first line is an error: `/usr/local/sbin/testbash: line 1: This is a lovey 7 words string: command not found`

Comment: Just remove the space: `exmple="This is a lovey 7 words   string"`

Comment: @DocWiki: Sorry for the typo. I simply pasted what was in the question without thinking.

Comment: It works fine now. Maybe I copied some html code the last time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DocWiki: See the briefer version in my edited answer. Thanks to ennuikiller for the idea.

Comment: @Dennis: Your first version had the advantage of normalizing whitespace. This one (like @ennuikiller's one) does not, although it is faster and much shorter.

Comment: This command looks like magic: `newstring=${exmple// ? / }`, but it works! cool!

Comment: @thkala: I thought it did normalize the whitespace because it changed three spaces to one as in the OP's sample, however I didn't consider longer runs. Thanks for pointing that out. It's a simple fix.

Comment: @Dennis: it also does not normalize whitespace in locations where a single-letter word is not involved, such as e.g. between "words" and "string" in the OP's example. Your loop-based method works in that case too.

Comment: @thkala: yes it gets that one because the middle of the three spaces matches the `?`. See my edited answer for a couple of ways to normalize.

Comment: @Dennis: you are right. It would handle this case because there are three spaces. If there were two... well better just normalize the whole string afterwards, anyway. +1

Answer (score 4):

sed does this nicely:

```
example="This is a lovey 7 words string"
echo $example | sed -e 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9]\{1\} / /g'
```

Comment: The `\{1\}` is redundant - `sed -e 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9] / /g'` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9] / /g'` won't remove double or more spaces.

This will:

```
echo "This is a lovey 7 words   string" | sed 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9 ] / /g'
```

And this will remove any spaces from the beginning or from the end:

```
echo "   This is a lovey 7 words   string  " | sed 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9 ] / /g' | sed 's/^ *\| *$//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can also make it:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) s=(length($i)>2? s($i)FS : s); print s}' <<< "This is a lovey 7 words   string"
This lovey words string
```

#### Explanation

The idea is to loop through all the fields of the string storing those being bigger than a given size. Finally, print the stored string.

- `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)` loop through all fields.
- `s=(length($i)>2? s($i)FS : s)` if the length of the word is bigger than 2, then append it to the current sentence. Otherwise, not.
- `print s` print the final string.