# Regex correct but not working in sed for 2-character words

Tags: regex, sed

I've used regex101.com and a few others to check that this is correct and it seems to be. I want to remove all words which are two characters long or less. My current implementation is:

```
head -n 10 abstracts.txt | sed 's/ [a-zA-Z]{1,2} //g'
```

And it's just not doing anything. I would like to go from something like this:

> This is a short sentence.

To this:

> This short sentence.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux bash: delete the word whose length is less than 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417663/linux-bash-delete-the-word-whose-length-is-less-than-2)

Comment: you have to escape the curly braces or use sed with -r option.

Comment: @fedorqui `sed -e 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9] / /g'` works fine for one letter words, but how would I extend that to two letter words?

Comment: `sed -e 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9]{2} / /g'` - Or `{1,2}` for 1 or 2 characters

Answer (score 3):

Escape the curly brackets and use word boundary:

```
head -n 10 abstracts.txt | sed 's/ [a-zA-Z]\{1,2\}\b//g'
```

Comment: This will also works, `sed 's/\b[a-zA-Z]\{1,2\} //g'`

Comment: Note this will fail deleting 1-2 words if they are in the first place in the line.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use empty spaces use `\b` for word boundaries:

```
echo 'This is a short sentence' | sed -e 's/\b[a-zA-Z]\{1,2\}\b//g'
This   short sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for test, using `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (length($i)<3) $i="";gsub(/  +/," ")}1'
This short sentence.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e 's/\b\w\w\?\b\s\+\|\s\+\w\w\?$//g' file
```

This removes one or two character words and the following spaces throughout a line or the preceeding spaces and one or two character word at the end of a line.